# Using facebook comment plugin in Portuguese not english

Tags: facebook

I am trying to implement different facebook plugins in my website, like share, comment, like-box etc. I'm using the common code below for all of them,

```
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/pt_BR/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=*************&version=v2.0";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
```

I came to know that simply changing the en_US to pt_BR in the js.src field it should work. But after changing to pt_BR it is still showing in English. Is there anything else that needs to be done beside this?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/faqs/#faqi18n
- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/internationalization#plugins

> Note that this only applies to plugins and buttons that are directly integrated with your site. Dialogs like the Login Dialog will still be rendered in the language that the person has picked as their native language on Facebook, even if it's different than the language you've selected.

The docs more or less state the same as you wrote. You could check the locale setting of your browser, and/or your Facebook language.

If you think everything is correct on your end, open a bug report with Facebook to have them check it.